# Rewrite SQL and use of group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written below sql for one of the requirement and is fetching my results. But, I am wondering if there is any better way of writing this query rather than using alias table as A.

```
SELECT A.*,B.OPRDEFNDESC FROM 
( select OPRID_ENTERED_BY ,COUNT(*)
  from ps_req_hdr  
  where entered_dt > '01-JUL-2012'
  GROUP BY OPRID_ENTERED_BY
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) A, PSOPRDEFN B
WHERE A.OPRID_ENTERED_BY=B.OPRID
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a simple INNER JOIN to do the same thing...

```
SELECT A.OPRID_ENTERED_BY, COUNT(*), B.OPRDEFNDESC
FROM ps_req_hdr A
JOIN PSOPRDEFN B ON A.OPRID_ENTERED_BY = B.OPRID
WHERE A.entered_dt > '01-JUL-2012'
GROUP BY A.OPRID_ENTERED_BY, B.OPRDEFNDESC
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

**NOTE**

As per the comments below, the COUNT(*) result for this query will NOT include records that don't have corresponding matches in table B, and it will inflate for non-unique matches in table B.  What this means is: if `B.OPRID` is not a unique field or if `A.OPRID_ENTERED_BY` is not a foreign key for `B.OPRID` then this answer will not yield the same results as the original query.

Comment: Are you sure this is equivalent?

Comment: This wouldn't give identical results.  In your query, the count would be of only records that meet the join predicate, where the count in the OP's version would include records in the ps_req_hdr that meet the WHERE predicate, but might not meet the JOIN predicate.

Comment: It's equivalent to the OP's query only if `OPRID` is the primary or a unique key of table B (`PSOPRDEFN`)

Comment: But isn't this being asked? "I am wondering if there is any better way of writing this query rather than using alias table as A" not something else?

Comment: @S.P. "better" is not the same as "with different results"

Comment: @Narry, ypercube and Jim are correct that the results can vary from the original query you posted.  This would depend on whether all rows in table A have a corresponding row in table B (in which case this answer would suffice).

Comment: I am on your side, @ypercube. Thats what I am saying. "better" DOES NOT mean different results.

Comment: @PinnyM, you're probably right that the original query isn't exactly what was intended; just wanted to point out that in his version, if a record exists in ps_req_hdr with entered_date > '01-JUL-2012', but with no record in PSOPRDEFN to match its OPRID_ENTERED_BY value, then it would be included in the count still, while in your version it would not be.

Comment: @Jim: No, you are wrong, that is not the problem. In that case you mention, no result would be shown in either version.

Comment: All, Thanks for explaining the difference between the 2 queries. In this situation, both the queries are returning same results as OPRID_ENTERED_BY exists in B table always.

Comment: @Narry: What's the primary key of table B?

Comment: @ypercube, I assume you are raising the possibility that multiple matches for B (if it's not unique) will inflate the count accordingly.  In the OP's query, the count would not be inflated but duplicate rows would be returned.  In all likelihood this is not the case, but good catch...